# Remove click event on item with added class of 'selected'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new here and new to JavaScript and JQuery.

I've been working on a little script to get a part of my page switching videos from Youtube.

The problem I have is when a thumbnail has the class of 'selected' added I want to disable the click function to stop the video reloading - is there a simple way around this?

I attempted to put another bit of JQuery in to find the item with the 'selected' class and return false but I know this is wrong because that will stop the default browser behaviour and not the click event.

Also I'd be very grateful for explanations on code suggestions and also suggestions to improve/streamline my JQuery code.

Thanks in advance!

**HTML:**

```
<iframe id="vid" width="980" height="551" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/hziG9Nr6KHU?&rel=0&amp;controls=4&amp;wmode=transparent&modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<ul id="videos">
    <li id="one">
        <a class="selected" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/hziG9Nr6KHU?&rel=0&amp;controls=2&amp;wmode=transparent&modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=1&autoplay=1 ">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x180" />
            <span class="AGreg">Vid1</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="two" class="left">
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/V1bFr2SWP1I?&rel=0&amp;controls=2&amp;wmode=transparent&modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=1&autoplay=1 ">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x180" />
            <span class="AGreg">Vid12</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="three" class="left">
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XLgYAHHkPFs?&rel=0&amp;controls=2&amp;wmode=transparent&modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=1&autoplay=1 ">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x180" />
            <span class="AGreg">Vid3</span>
        </a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
iframe#vid{width:980px;height:551px;}
.selected img{
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */}

#videos .cursorD a{cursor:default!important}

#videos a:hover img{
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */}

ul#videos{margin:20px 0;padding:0;}
ul#videos img{}
ul#videos li{float:left;width:320px;}
ul#videos li.left{margin:0 0 0 10px}
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("ul#videos li a").click(function(){
            $("iframe").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
            $(this).closest('ul#videos').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).parent().addClass('selected cursorD');
            return false;
        })  
    });
```

**CODEPEN**: http://codepen.io/PixelsPencil/pen/uljzy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for replying again! I've had a play and put something up on jsfiddle but think it's more broke now than it ever was haha. When I click something with notselected class all thumbs change class and when I click a selected class the video loads in the parent instead of switching the attr in the iframe - any ideas where I've gone wrong?? jsfiddle.net/wvPnA

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the event handler on the clicked video like you want to, but that requires a bit of code. An easier and (i.m.h.o. more elegant) solution is to adjust your selector / event handler hookup so it only gets executed on elements that do not have the class "selected":

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul#videos li a:not('.selected')").click(function(){
        $("iframe").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
        $(this).closest('ul#videos').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).parent().addClass('selected cursorD');
        return false;
    })  
});
```

I have to confess, I didn't test it and I'm not 100% sure on the evaluation priority of `:xyz()` type selectors. To be more certain of what is happening, you could either change the single selector to a selector chain:

```
$("ul#videos").find("li").find("a:not('.selected')").click( ... );
```

or even better, hook the event handler to a parent object, but only have it trigger on distinct elements (also expressed through a selector):

```
$("ul#videos").on("click", "li a:not('.selected')", function() { ... });
```

This has the added charm that the handler will automatically work for `li`s that are added *after* wiring the event handler.

Comment: Hi Uweb,

Thank you for the swift reply and suggestions.

I tried all but for some reason they seem to fail, I even tried them on my codepen and instead of switching the video where the iframe is it loaded the full video embed in to the window so somewhere along the lines I've gone wrong with the code or something is not right but as you said you had not test it so no expecting you to go all out and fix it just happy you are trying to assist :)

Comment: Version 1:

 $(document).ready(function(){
  //$("ul#videos li a").click(function(){
  $("ul#videos").find("li").find("a:not('.selected')")
   $("iframe").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
         $(this).closest('ul#videos').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
         $(this).parent().addClass('selected cursorD');
   return false;
  }) 
 });

Comment: Version 2:

 $(document).ready(function(){
  //$("ul#videos li a").click(function(){
  /* $("ul#videos").find("li").find("a:not('.selected')") */
  $("ul#videos").on("click", "li a:not('.selected')", function() {
   $("iframe").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
         $(this).closest('ul#videos').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
         $(this).parent().addClass('selected cursorD');
   return false;
  }) 
 });

Comment: Version three was as per your code in your first example.

Comment: I believe another problem is that the click handler adds the `selected` class to the parent (that should be the `<li>` element), yet on your HTML code it is on the `<a>` element. That would mean that the `:not('.selected')` part (whether it's attached to `<a>` or `<li>`) will either never work, or just once.
EDIT: I created a very basic JSFiddle to demonstrate approach 3) in my original posting: http://jsfiddle.net/a9qNz/

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work - asked a few people for help and a colleague came up with this still not sure why/how this works but it does.

```
var VideoLoader = { 
registerClickHandlers: function() {     
    $("ul#videos li a").click(VideoLoader.showSelectedVideo);
},  
    showSelectedVideo: function() {

        if(!VideoLoader.checkVideoIsAlreadyPlaying(this)) {

            $("iframe").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));

       $(this).closest('ul#videos').find('.selected').removeClass('selected cursorD');
       $(this).parent().addClass('selected cursorD');

    }

    return false;
},

    checkVideoIsAlreadyPlaying: function(clickedObject) {           
        return $(clickedObject).parent().hasClass("selected");  
    }
};

$(document).ready(VideoLoader.registerClickHandlers);
```

Updated my Codepen here: http://codepen.io/PixelsPencil/pen/uljzy